# Run code inside a button without clicking it

Tags: javascript

the following part of code is from a pop-up alert window, in the example page on how to use there is a button that says "Error", and when you click it the window appears.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger notification" data-verti-pos="bottom" data-horiz- pos="right" data-message="<i class='fa fa-frown-o' style='padding-right:6px'></i> Oops... Something went wrong. Hope we don\'t see me again." data-type="error" type="button"></button>
```

The problem is that i want to call the window without needing to click the button, i am trying to call it inside this if conditional.

```
if(codigo=="matricula_longitud"){
        //I know the part of code below is totally wrong
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert-warning fade in"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button><strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, youre not looking too good.</div>';
    return "si";
}
```

I am new to programming so any advice will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the content in a function, which is called from the event handler of your button and other function where you're showing the window without the requirement to click on a button.

```
var showWindow = function() {
    alert("La matricula es muy corta")
    //I know the part of code below is totally wrong
    document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML='...';
    return "si";
};
```

And then in your button handler

```
if(codigo=="matricula_longitud"){ 
    return showWindow();
}
```

And in your other function, just call `showWindow()` if you want to show it to the user.

A little remark though, if you want to check a condition, it's best to use strict equality checks, `===` or `!==` instead of `==` or `!=`. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

At least, you can use jquery

```
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-danger notification" data-verti-pos="bottom" data-horiz- pos="right" data-message="<i class='fa fa-frown-o' style='padding-right:6px'></i> Oops... Something went wrong. Hope we don\'t see me again." data-type="error" type="button"></button>

$('#myBtn').click();
```